# How to execute Jquery-code in a dialog which received its content via $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Let's say the following code exists in template_A popping up a dialog which displays content from template_B.

The html is presented fine in the dialog but unfortunately any javascript included in template_B does not run.

Jquery & Jquery-ui are included in template_A.

template_B has no javascript-includes as it is represented by a div belonging to template_A.

JS in template_A :

```
var win = $(document.createElement('div'));
$.get(url, function (html) {
  win.html(html);
  win.dialog("open");
});
```

template_B :

```
<div id="content">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      // this never executes,
      // js-debugging won't enter this part...
    });
  </script>

</div>
```

Comment: FYI: `$(document.createElement('div'))` can be written as `$('<div/>')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code block you're talking about is only triggered once the DOM is finished loading. Just inserting html into an existing document doesn't trigger this event. If there's a lot of HTML you're getting from this request, maybe you should break it up into two separate requests like so:

```
var win = $(document.createElement('div'));
$.get(urlA, function (html) {
  win.html(html);
  $.getStript(urlB);
  win.dialog("open");
});
```

Where urlA requests the HTML and urlB requests the Javascript.

Comment: I need to use $.get as the returned html contains an addional form which is displayed to the user, so I am wondering how can I execute the js in another way?

Comment: Running `$(function(){})` after the DOM was loaded still runs the function.

Comment: @recalcitrant, I modified my answer so you can get the html and js separately.